# Use chrome instead of chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I'm using Python with Selenium but I need to use it with extension (and probably with cookies). Extension is uploaded from ZIP file and I need to change something in this extension settings after instalation so it will be hard to reupload extension every start of project. Is there aby option to use it like that? I was trying to use profile from normal chrome but it doesn't work for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    service = Service('D:\\chromedriver.exe') # your driver path
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument \
        (r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\czarn\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data") # your chrome user data directory
    chrome_options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Member') # the profile with the extensions loaded
    window = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
```

I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\czarn\PycharmProjects\trening\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    window = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

Comment: Show us the code that you've tried so far ? it will help us narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you can use an already existing Chrome Profile.

Example code where the paths are referring to my machine but it should be easy for you to adapt to your use case.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service('C:\\Users\\nicoc\\PycharmProjects\\WriteAI\\chromedriver.exe') # your driver path

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument \
    (r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\nicoc\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data") # your chrome user data directory
chrome_options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Default') # the profile with the extensions loaded
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

The code works for Selenium v4 (it's still in beta but it works fine)